# Pandas - Delete multiple columns based on column position

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with an index, and with 19 columns that don't have column names. I want to keep the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 7th columns and drop the rest.
I've tried this that is dropping the columns and leaving the 4 I need, but is there a cleaner way?

```
ds_drop1 = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds_drop1 = df.drop(df.columns[[5]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
ds_drop1 = df.drop(df.columns[[7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: df = df.iloc[:,3:6] ?

Comment: @BENY that only gives me 3rd, 4th, 5th. I need the 7th columns as well

Comment: @
df = df.iloc[:,3:7].. then

Comment: @BENY sorry! I want to skip the 6th, and get 7th. so 3-5 and 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case doing `numpy.r_` with `iloc`(Adding `copy` for prevent the future copy warning)

```
#import numpy as np
out = df.iloc[:,np.r_[3:6,7]].copy()
```

Comment: this worked thanks! but when I try to add names to my columns like this: df.columns =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] I see the error:  Expected axis has 19 elements, new values have 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

Use `.iloc` for specific column or row locations. Note that the column positions are zero-indexed, so `[2:6:7]` will return the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns. The first `:` selects all rows:

Update based on your question - this will include the 7th column:

`ds_drop1 = df.iloc[:,2:6,7]`

Comment: thanks for responding! I want to get the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 7th, and skip the 6th

Comment: Have amended but seems the answer above covers what you needed